# Check Minus Value In Uitextview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I've created one calculator.In that calculator,I've used UITextview for displaying calculation.Now, I've to check that the total calculation is in minus digits,For Example  (-234.00).so, I've to gave alert message.how can i check that there is a minus value in UITextview.

Comment: You want to check if the first character of the text is a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
 if( [textview.text hasPrefix:@"-"])
{
//do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: A `;` after if would not execute the following block, i guess a typo, edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is in string (directly fetching from UITextView as NSSTring) by

```
if([textView.text hasPrefix:@"-"]){

    //you alert goes here

}
```

Also if you are calculating from some numbers and wnat to check if the value is negative then

```
if(calcuatedNumber < 0){ //this is not NSNumber for NSNumber use [... integerValue]

   //you alert goes here

}
```